# Backward Elimination in R (Automating the process)

Tags: r, linear-regression, modeling

I'm trying to use the backward elimination technique to get a four-predictor multiple regression model:

Here are my commands:

```
#Packages
library(Stat2Data)
library(mosaic)
library(car)
library(dplyr)

#Load data (this dataset is included in the Stat2Data package)
data("MLBStandings2016")
#Drop Team names, Wins and Losses(I only want quantitative variables)
MLBdata <- MLBStandings2016[c(-3,-4,-1,-2)]

#I begin with a full model(16 predictors) with Winning percentage as the response
full=lm(WinPct~.,data=MLBdata)
summary(full)

#Find the MSE for the full model(I will be using MSE(basically Mallow's Cp) as the criteria for choosing models)
MSE <- ((summary(full))$sigma^2)

#Use the step( ) command for backward elimination
step(full, scale=MSE, direction="backward")
```

The problem is, the backward elimination process(using Mallow's Cp as the criteria for elimination) stops when there are still eight-predictors left, which is not what I want.

Alternatively, I have tried to use the p-value of individual terms as the criteria for eliminating predictors; the commands are as follows:

```
#I load a new package
library(olsrr)
#use the ols function to do backward elimination
ols_step_backward_p(full)
```

I still have the same problem where the elimination process stops too soon (before there are only four predictors left).

I'm thinking maybe I should use R^2 OR adj R^2 but I do not know if there's a function that I could use where I can include an argument specifying which criteria I can use, or if anybody knows of a great way to automate this process.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want a 4-variable model specifically? Generally backwards regression functions stop when they reach a specific stopping condition - for step(), it's that the AIC of the new model (without the variable) will not be less than the AIC of the previous model. If you're using p-values, it will keep removing variables until all variables left have p-values smaller than whatever cutoff the function uses. I don't see anywhere in your code where you told the function to choose a specific number of variables, and I don't think that would actually be a good idea.

Comment: (ctd) Your model will be much more robust if you select variables, no matter how many, that meet a specific criterion, than if you choose an arbitrary cutoff for number of variables. If you really need that, you will need to experiment with increasing the k parameter in step() to lower the p-value cutoff until you get the desired number of variables. But you may remove variables that would be considered significant in most cases if you do that.

Comment: Hi bsg, Thanks for your insight. Unfortunately, it's a HW problem, and the question specifies that it be a four-predictor model (which doesn't make sense indeed). I guess I have to add an argument "prem=" to get the desired number of variables. Thanks again for your insight. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Ah. Ok. So yes, prem in ols_step_backward_p or k in step. Good luck!

Comment: @YangWu: the central question is "What are your criteria for taking another step?". If you know that, you can write you're own step function (that also considers 'don't stop if more than 4 variables'). If you don't know how to do it yourself, people here will help. But again, the criteria must be clear.

Comment: @Georgery: Hi Georgery! Thanks for your insight. My preferred criteria for taking another step is "relatively high" p-values. Do you know of a way to include an argument "don't stop if more than 4 variables" in the step function? I've tried to use the help function in R, but the scope of the documentation and examples is rudimentary. I've somewhat solved the problem by adding the "prem=" argument and setting it to a low threshold to artificially induce R to continue the elimination process. But I'd be grateful to receive any other suggestions. Please let me know.